# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'manage.py'

Tags: python, django

I am facing a rather strange issue. I am trying to get my django app started using the `python manage.py runserver`. But I get a `FileNotFoundError`. I have checked multiple time. The file is in the directory from where I am running the `python manage.py runserver` command.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\New folder (2)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\New folder (2)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\New folder (2)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\New folder (2)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 58, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\New folder (2)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\New folder (2)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 97, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\New folder (2)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 106, in run
    autoreload.main(self.inner_run, None, options)
  File "C:\New folder (2)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 333, in main
    reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\New folder (2)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 299, in python_reloader
    reloader_thread()
  File "C:\New folder (2)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 275, in reloader_thread
    change = fn()
  File "C:\New folder (2)\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 205, in code_changed
    stat = os.stat(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'manage.py'
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was doing wrong. In one one of the codes, I was changing the directory using `os.chdir(location)`. I have made the changes, it works now.